# Best place to store custom functions?

Tags: wordpress

I need to rewrite some functions. For instance, some of the functions here:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php

Should I go ahead and just add them to the end of the same file, or is there a special place that I am supposed to use?

[edit]

Forgot to clarify that I don't want to override the existing functions. I want to copy and edit them under a new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are referring to is a core WP files which resides inside wp-includes directory. **Nothing inside this directory or wp-admin directory should be touched/modified**. If you modify anything inside the core, during the WP version upgrade, the modified functionalities will be lost.

WordPress provides ways to modify the existing behaviour of the functionalities. **Hooks(Actions/Filters)** can be used to override/modify the functionality. Try create a new plugin and add your code there inside wp-content/plugins directory OR you can add your code inside functions.php file of the current active theme.

Hooks: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

Comment: I will add them to functions.php. Thanks.